# MySQL Query for substring and count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have done quite a bit of research and found some useful sql examples but can't seem to get exactly what I want.

```
1. Employee Table
ID, EmployeeName

2. Absence Table
ID, Employee_ID, Reason
```

I need a report with distinct first letters of the employee's name and another column with a count of how many times that certain category was absent!

Comment: Nope, by category I meant the count of the items in the first column. sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
Select LEFT(a.EmployeeName, <number of chars you want>), COUNT(b.EmployeeId) 
FROM Employee a, Absence b 
WHERE a.ID = b.Employee_ID GROUP BY a.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select substr(EmployeeName, 1, 1) as emp_name, count(*) from
Employee e inner join Absence a on e.ID=a.Employee_ID
group by emp_name
```